# How to upload documents with new python-gdata (2.0.16)?

Tags: python, gdata, google-docs, gdata-api, google-docs-api

With python-gdata 2.0.14, I used the following pieces of code to create and upload documents:

```
# To create a document
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.client
from gdata.data import MediaSource

gdClient = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source="my-app")
gdClient.ssl = True
gdClient.ClientLogin("login", "pa$$word", gdClient.source)
ms = MediaSource(file_path="temp.html", content_type="text/html")
entry = gdClient.Upload(ms, "document title")
print "uploaded, url is", entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

and

```
# To update a document
entry.title.text = "updated title"
entry = gdClient.Update(entry, media_source=ms, force=True)
print "updated, url is", entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

However, this code does no longer work with python-gdata 2.0.16 because [`DocsClient` class](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.docs.client.html) does no more have `Upload` and `Update` functions.

I tried to use this

```
# Try to create a document
gdClient = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source="my-app")
gdClient.ssl = True
gdClient.ClientLogin("login", "pa$$word", gdClient.source)
ms = MediaSource(file_path="temp.html", content_type="text/html")
entry = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type=gdata.docs.data.DOCUMENT_LABEL, title="document title")
self.resource = gdClient.CreateResource(entry, media=ms)
```

… but I get this error:

```
gdata.client.Unauthorized: Unauthorized - Server responded with: 401, 'Token invalid'
```

Can anybody tell me where's my mistake and how should I use that new API?

P.S. [The documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html) hasn't been updated and still uses the old-style code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having issues with this recently too. This worked for me:

```
import gdata.docs.data
import gdata.docs.client

client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source='your-app')
client.api_version = "3"
client.ssl = True
client.ClientLogin("your@email.com", "password", client.source)

filePath = "/path/to/file"
newResource = gdata.docs.data.Resource(filePath, "document title")

media = gdata.data.MediaSource()
media.SetFileHandle(filePath, 'mime/type')

newDocument = client.CreateResource(newResource, create_uri=gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_UPLOAD_URI, media=media)
```

**Edit**: Added the packages to import to avoid confusion

Comment: Thanks! I still get some errors with Python 3 version (which I built using 2to3), but I'll try to sort those out later.

Comment: Hello. Your example kind of works for me but instead of document being placed in the folder I want (or should I say to the url I give) in is placed to my account. the document is suppose to be seen for everybody inside a group